# State is undefined from other function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I' m trying to get eventsData from updateScoreHandler. I can't understand, why when I type in input, in console is showing undefined (initial state). In console whe it's starting is showing: changed undefined and after this: changed {elements: Array(2), data: Array(2)} (correct data)

```
    const [eventsData, setEventsData] = useState<{
       elements: JSX.Element[];
       data: { id: string; home?: number; away?: number }[];
    }>();

    useEffect(() => {
       loadEvents();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
       console.log('hook', eventsData);
    }, [eventsData]);



   const loadEvents = async () => {
       const res = await axios.get(BACKEND_URL + '/events');
       const events = res.data.map((event: MatchType) => (
           <input type="number" onChange={(e) => updateScoreHandler()} />
       )

    setEventsData({ elements: events, data: res.data });
   };

    const updateScoreHandler = () => {
    console.log(id, value, target, eventsData);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, don't store JSX elements in state, your probably running into stale scope problems or something, i.e. at the time of storing your inputs in state updateScoreHandler will have eventsData as undefined

try something like -

```
const loadEvents = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(BACKEND_URL + '/events');
    setEvents(res.data);
};
```

then

```
const updateScoreHandler = (event) => {
    // do something with event?
};

...

return (
   ...

   {events.map(event => (
       <input type="number" onChange={(e) => updateScoreHandler(event)} />
    ))}

   ...
)
```

Comment: I had no idea that JSX elements in state are incorrect. Many thanks!